# can't open /dev/tty(2,3,4). No such file or directory

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

When starting QEMU with Busybox (1.30.1) (lkeep getting error
can't open /dev/tty2: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/tty2: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/tty3: No such file or directory
Busybox is running because when I run ls, I see the directories.
Found suggestions online to edit inittab but don't have one in /etc. So I put one there but didn't fix the issue. INITTAB is is enabled in the Busybox .config

thanks

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 3):

from target root console:

```
 ln -sf /dev/null /dev/tty2
 ln -sf /dev/null /dev/tty3
```